# Not able to find unique values in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, unique-values

I have some data in excel, I want to select unique values based on multiple criteria.

The data that I have in excel is

[image]

---

Name    Medals  Year

- A     2       2017
- B 3   2018
- C 5   2018
- A     1   2016
- C 4   2017
- B 7   2018
- A 1   2017
- D 4   2016

I want to get the count of unique names who got medals >2 and <6 and year is 2017 or 2018.

So the result that I should get is 2 as B and C satisfy the criteria.

I have searched in internet about his and I got some formula using SUMPRODUCT and COUNTIFS, the formula used is

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIFS(A2:A9,A2:A9,B2:B9,">2",B2:B9,"<6",C2:C9,">2016",C2:C9,"<2019" ))
```

But I am getting error in this case.

Please suggest me how can I get the desired count. Thanks in advance!!

**Note**: This data is excerpted from huge data.

Answer (score 3):

So if this is your data:

[image]

The formula used in `E9`:

```
{=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF((B2:B9>2)*(B2:B9<6)*(C2:C9>2016)*(C2:C9<2019),MATCH(A2:A9,A2:A9,0)),ROW(A2:A9)-ROW(A2)+1)>0))}
```

See [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-text-values-with-criteria) for more in depth explaination.

Comment: Impressive array formula. Yeah I was wondering, because I had a formula of `COUNTIFS()` prepared, but could not figure a way to pass it to a `FREQUENCY`

Comment: @Sivakesav, You need to make your references absolute! Except the last `ROW(A2)`

Comment: Thank you so much @Jvdv , your explanation helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a [pivot-table](/questions/tagged/pivot-table) with

- Year filtered as as `>=2017`

  [image]
- Name Values between `2` and `6`

  [image]
- Which yields the following result:

  [image]
- and then we simply count unique values *(excluding blank cells `<>""`)*

[image]

Would say this formula is a bit more user-friendly and makes for a better visual representation of the data, but if you just want a formula, then absolutely go for @JvdV's solution :)