# Formula for unique records that satisfy a row condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, sumproduct

I want to be able to provide a count of distinct values of one column ("ID", in column B below) where a value in the respective row (eg "Value" in Column C below) meets a criteria (eg <>0) below. As you can see, I can easily compute the list of unique ID's (cell B8, with formula in C8) but can't fathom how to pair this with the discovery of non-zero values.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've formulated an answer to sort of a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56059103/not-able-to-find-unique-values-in-excel/56059438#56059438). Particulary handy if you want to extend with multiple criteria.

In your case it would look a bit more symplistic cause you have numeric values (ID's)

```
{=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(Table1[Value]>0,Table1[ID])Table1[ID])>0))}
```

Entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Would that be Frequency for Interval? FWIW I much prefer your frequency method to the countif method.

Comment: @TomSharpe, i'm sorry, it should be frequency. Interval is the dutch equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the double unary operator (`--`) to revert a true/false to 0 or 1 then use that in the sumproduct like so:

`=SUMPRODUCT((1/COUNTIF($B$3:$B$6,$B$3:$B$6))*(--($C$3:$C$6<>0)))`

Answer (score 0):

Here's another (non array) option

```
=SUM(($C$3:$C$6<>0)/COUNTIFS($B$3:$B$6,$B$3:$B$6))
```

Or, if the data is a Table as your image suggests

```
=SUM((YourTableName[Value]<>0)/COUNTIFS(YourTableName[ID],YourTableName[ID]))
```

Comment: Nod to @Glitch 's answer, only added it as some might consider it "simpler"